# auto login in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a login in xamarin forms and give the user the possibility to log in automatically when opening the app.
What is the best way to develop this? Any example that can help me ?.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You need to use a refresh token. Save the refresh token in a secure storage, so when the authentication token expires you send your service the refresh token.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=ios)? or [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.properties?view=xamarin-forms)

You Have a method to generate a token 
I'd Recommend [Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.8)

E.G:

```cs
// Create and display the value of two GUIDs.
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(g);
Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());

// This code example produces a result similar to the following:

// 0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e
// 7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7
```

Then you can save it to either Properties or Prefrences

```cs
Preferences.Set("Token", g)//g = The token string;

Application.Current.Properties ["Token"] = g//Your Token Variable;
```

And when the application Launches you can check if the token is there.

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("Token"))
{
    var Token= Application.Current.Properties ["Token"] as string;
    // do something with Token
}

 if (Preferences.ContainsKey("Token ")){

   var Token = Preferences.Get("Token ", "default_value");
}
```

You can also save the Token to Some kind of database, Like SQL,Sqlite, Firebase ect.

Then you can compare against the var Token and if they match The user is logged in.

Now The question is very vague, We have no idea how your logging users in, If its fire-base for example you get a token to refresh the login as Nestor Mentioned.